# How do i use async function when a button is pressed?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use async function when a button is pressed, I need the button pressed to share data. the button onPress code look like like this.

```
    <TouchableOpacity
      disabled={buttonDisabled}
      onPress={Share}
      style={[
        styles.btTouchable,
        buttonDisabled && styles.buttonDisabled,
      ]}>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

And the function i want to do the sharing is look like :

```
async function Share() {
    try {
      let locationData = await new LocationData().getLocationData();

      const jsonData = base64.encode(JSON.stringify(locationData));
      const title = '';
      const filename = '';
      const message = '';
      const url = 'data:application/json;base64,' + jsonData;
      const options = Platform.select({
        ios: {
          activityItemSources: [
            {
              placeholderItem: { type: 'url', content: url },
              item: {
                default: { type: 'url', content: url },
              },
              subject: {
                default: title,
              },
              linkMetadata: { originalUrl: url, url, title },
            },
            {
              placeholderItem: { type: 'text', content: message },
              item: {
                default: { type: 'text', content: message },
                message: null, // Specify no text to share via Messages app.
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        default: {
          title,
          subject: title,
          url: url,
          message: message,
          filename: filename,
        },
      });

      Share.open(options)
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err.message, err.code);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  }
```

How do i make async function work when a press a button? Thanks very much

Comment: The function is actually async now. What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try using the function this way:

```js
Share = async () => {
  .....
  .....
}
```

and call the function this way:

```js
   <TouchableOpacity
     disabled={buttonDisabled}
     onPress={this.Share}
     style={[
       styles.btTouchable,
       buttonDisabled && styles.buttonDisabled,
     ]}>
   </TouchableOpacity>
```

[Edit]

To use it with hooks, you can follow this article: [React Hooks Basics— Building a React Native App with React Hooks](https://medium.com/crowdbotics/build-a-react-native-app-with-react-hooks-5498e1d5fdf6)

Comment: Wiliam Brochensque  Thanks for your response, It works , but  how do i call Hooks with this function

Comment: I'm adding to the answer a article.

Comment: well, you should added it to the answer on the beginning so.
but put the entire code on the answer (if not already) with the error message, then i will search for the problem for you

Comment: @Brochensque ,                                                                                                             Share = async () => {
  .....
  .....
}    displays two share dialog window , how do i  make it to display only one share dialog window